# Java - рисование с Canvas

Tags: canvas, java, классы, graphics

Как задать параметры функциям Canvas из другого класса?

Допустим, есть класс Picture:

```
 static class Picture extends Canvas {
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(0,0,20,20);
    }
}
```

Как при создании объекта Picture задать, например, цвет того, что рисуется? Непонятно, как применить setColor() к созданному объекту

Comment: Может в конструктор передавать цвет?

Comment: Да, пришел к выводу, что просто сделать в классе переменную с дефолтным цветом и передавать значение при создании - проще всего. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно самому создать метод `setColor`, а используемые цвета хранить, например, в ассоциативном контейнере EnumMap. Примерный код:

```
public class Test {
    static class Picture extends Canvas{
         public enum ColorType{FONT_COLOR, BG_COLOR};
         private EnumMap<ColorType,Color> ColorMap;
         Picture(){
             ColorMap=new EnumMap(ColorType.class);
             /*цвет по умолчанию*/
             this.setColor(ColorType.BG_COLOR, new Color(0xFF0000));
         }
         public void setColor(ColorType type, Color value){
             ColorMap.put(type, value);
         }
         public void paint(Graphics g){
             g.setColor(ColorMap.get(ColorType.BG_COLOR));
         }
    }
    Test(){
        Picture myPic=new Picture();
        myPic.setColor(Picture.ColorType.BG_COLOR, new Color(0xFF0000));
    }

}
```

Comment: Немного громоздко получается для класса, который должен рисовать квадратики, но зато познавательно) Думаю, использую ColorMap в другом классе